# WOWZA LiveAutoRecord

Tags: wowza

I am tired of one problem so please make things clear to me.
Please read these following three points and help me out.

(1)
I have simply followed this https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-start-and-stop-live-stream-recordings-programmatically-livestreamrecordautorecord-example#documentation
I have attached my Application.xml. Now when I publish live stream name "test1" via FMLE it get recorded on server but when I run different instance of FMLE on different PC and publish live stream name "test2" it does not get record and I think it goes to previously recorded file "test1" (means no separate file being record, however there should be two files recorded test1 and test2).
Why this happenning ? 
Is this com.wowza.wms.plugin.livestreamrecord.module.ModuleAutoRecordAdvancedExample for single stream recording ? means If I publish stream A B C D , it will record them in one single file ? (probably the output file will be A.mp4 as A was first published stream ?)

(2) What is this https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-start-and-stop-live-stream-recordings-programmatically-imediastreamactionnotify3#comments module for ?
I have implement this code in Eclipse and successfully put jar in lib folder and configured everything. Now again I am not able to record different streams with their corresponding name. Means If I publish stream1 and stream2 then desired output should be two different files (in content folder) but again I see one single file being record ?

(3) Can I use ModuleLiveStreamRecord.java ? This was in older version of WOWZA but I have properly imported required jar and tested it.

My requirement is very simple:
As soon as users start publishing, WOWZA should start live recording. If 10 users publishing live, 10 files should be generate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate your response KBoek.
I sorted out issue but there were really debugging need if one doing custom module. I had to write custom module for live auto recording because I wanted HTTP authentication and then custom name of live recording.
                                      thanks again

Answer (score 4):

Don't make things more difficult than necessary (assuming you have Wowza 4.x; if you still have 3.x then I highly recommend to upgrade for free)

- Open the Engine Manager (http://your.server.com:8088)
- Go to "Applications" from the top menu
- Select your application from the left menu (e.g. "live")
- In the setup window for this application, click the blue Edit button
- Enable "Record all incoming streams"
- Click "Save"
- Click the orange "Restart now" button at the top
- Done

Every stream that is published via this application will now automatically be recorded. The default folder for recordings is the /content folder in your Wowza installation. You can change this on the same page under "Streaming File Directory" (make sure it's a directory on your local system, unless you really well understand how Wowza works)

The filename is always the streamname + ".mp4", but when you start a new recording while the file already exists, the old file will be renamed first.

Want to control recording manually? Start publishing first, then select "Incoming streams" from the left menu and use the big red dot button behind a stream name to start recording.

If your server produces any different behavior with regards to the file (re)naming or recording, then you may need to review your Wowza setup.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I wanted custom module and its done. My client can not share enginemanager credential so we have done http custom module and its working fine now. Again thanks for your response.