# record audio from browser and visualize in real time

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, webrtc, visualization

I am looking for a package which will take input of audio from browser through microphone then visualize it in the real time.Any javascript package available to implement.I check most of the audio visualizer but they need audio file .I want  the package should directly get it from microphone in browser and then show visualization.I am implementing it in the nodejs so need something in java script

Comment: here is a start: https://github.com/wayou/HTML5_Audio_Visualizer

Comment: Im still wondering why people who are asking questions do *not* read through [ask] :/

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: This thing required audio file.I need something which will visualize it in  a real time

Comment: i tried to fine a solution for this but not successful thats why i post it there

Comment: record audio, you need server streaming as if you use java red5, wowza or more expensive flash media server for actionscript way. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27110675/wowza-liveautorecord

Comment: Like [this](https://blog.mozilla.org/webrtc/fiddle-of-the-week-audio-constraints/)?

Answer (score 4):

Google search of "web audio api visualizer with microphone" should have obviously pulled some decent results for you :)

local microphone stream + Web Audio api + canvas are the main requirements here!

1. Start with this [volume meter](https://github.com/cwilso/volume-meter/) example that gets input from microphone using webrtc api and show some visuals in GUI
2. Explore more examples from https://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/

Comment: thankyou for your answer .I am able to do it at my own  using video.js for this .